# XML Parsing in SOAP Client

Tags: javascript, angularjs, soap-client

I am doing a soap call in angular using the soapclient.js while the response xml as below

```
<tag1>
   <tag2>a-b<tag2>
<tag1>
```

The parsed output has the value for the tag in an array of string . I am getting output as below for tag2

```
["a","-","b"]
```

What to do If I need the output "a-b" ?

Edit 1 :

Adding the parsing code

```
SOAPClient._node2object = function(node, wsdlTypes)
{
// null node
if(node == null)
    return null;
// text node
if(node.nodeType == 3 || node.nodeType == 4)
    return SOAPClient._extractValue(node, wsdlTypes);
// leaf node
if (node.childNodes.length == 1 && (node.childNodes[0].nodeType == 3 || node.childNodes[0].nodeType == 4))
    return SOAPClient._node2object(node.childNodes[0], wsdlTypes);
var isArray = false;
var tmpNodeNameObject = new Object;
for (var i = 0; !isArray && i < node.childNodes.length; i++) {
    if (typeof tmpNodeNameObject[node.childNodes[i].nodeName] == "undefined")
        tmpNodeNameObject[node.childNodes[i].nodeName] = true;
    else isArray = true;

}
var isarray = isArray || SOAPClient._getTypeFromWsdl(node.nodeName, wsdlTypes).toLowerCase().indexOf("arrayof") != -1;
// object node
if (!isarray) {
    var obj = null;
    if (node.hasChildNodes())
        obj = new Object();
    for (var i = 0; i < node.childNodes.length; i++) {
        var p = SOAPClient._node2object(node.childNodes[i], wsdlTypes);
        obj[node.childNodes[i].nodeName] = p;
    }
    return obj;
}
else
{
    // create node ref
    var l = new Array();
    for(var i = 0; i < node.childNodes.length; i++)
        l[l.length] = SOAPClient._node2object(node.childNodes[i], wsdlTypes);
    return l;
}
return null;
}
```

Comment: Try `yourArray.toString().replace(",","");`

Comment: @M.Wiśnicki Thanks for your comment and Yes it will work but Is there a way that I can do it at parsing level ? .

Comment: Can you share how you parsing it?

Comment: @M.Wiśnicki . I added the parsing code but for the complete file Please using the link https://github.com/andrewmcgivery/angular-soap/blob/master/soapclient.js